# Is it possible to add a button to a fieldset title in sencha touch?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I would like to add a button in the fieldset title. Maybe something like this:

```
var btn = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'my button'
});

...

xtype: 'fieldset',
title: 'my title' + btn
```

Is something like this possible. I really don't want to use a delegate to reference html for the tap event. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Behind the scene fieldset's title is a `Ext.Title` component. So do not use the

```
{xtype: 'fieldset', title: 'title'... }
```

but

```
{xtype: 'fieldset', items: [{xtype: 'titlebar', title: 'Title', items: [{xtype: 'button'...}], ...}],... }
```

Cheers, Oleg